# Switching node versions on Ubuntu 19 messes up npm

Tags: nodejs, npm

I am on Ubuntu 19.04. When I do ...

```
sudo n 9.11.2
```

... do some compiling here and return by ...

```
sudo n latest
```

then ...

```
npm -v
```

I get ...

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
```

I searched and found many contributions to fix it. Some advice snap, yarn, brew. The solutions differ depending on preference and operating system, apparently it hasn't been sorted out yet.

I cleaned up manually and could nicely reproduce the issue. Over and over again.

Please feel free to share and comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
n latest          # switch to the latest version of node
which npm         # check if you have multiple installations should give one
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove npm 
sudo apt-get clean
npm -v            # check if npm is really removed 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall npm
exit              # close the terminal for npm is sticky
```

Open a new Terminal and check with npm -v if done